# How to get a average of column(in a group) in SSRS

Tags: sql, ssrs-2014

Thank you in advance.

I want the average amount spent on "Pants" in "Men" section.

I have a SSRS report and I am trying find the average of a column *Deals* (inside a grouped column "Men") but i am unable to do it.

This is my expression:

```
=Avg(IIf(Fields!Men.Value Like "Pants"
    , Fields!GrossSalesprice.Value
    , Nothing)
  , "dataset")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you already have a group defined and a line printing for the group it should be as simple as avg(Fields!GrossSalesprice.Value) or even Avg(GrossSalesprice)

Comment: I dont have the grouping for Pants in teh men section

Comment: y using like instead "=" !? ..